# Is it possible to run a query using Orion where the searching criteria is given by attributes value?

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware

As I create entities in an Orion server, I can search by ID, as flat or using regular expressions:

```
http://<localhost>:1026/v1/queryContext
```

Content:

```
{
  "entities": [
  {
    "type": "Sensor",
    "isPattern": "true",
    "id": "sensor_1.*"
  }
  ],
  "attributes": ["temperature","humidity"]
}
```

In the above example I'd get all objects of type "Sensor" whose ID starts with "sensor_1", and their attributes "temperature" and "humidity". I wonder if there is any way that would allow me to search by specific attribute value, for example to get those sensors whose humidity is over "60.2", or this selection must be done over the retrieved data queried by ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in the current Orion version (0.19.0) but it will be possible in the future. Have a look to the `attribute::<name>` filter with the `=` operator [in this document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f4m624nmO3jRjNalGE11lFLQixnfCENMV6dc54wUCCg/edit#gid=2).